# Preloaded operator delete deallocation size

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I need to get the size of the object being destroyed inside an operator delete but all I have is a void pointer. (`void operator delete(void*)`)

Is there any way to access that information? This doesn't need to be a portable solution; I only care about gcc on Linux.)

Comment: Could you give some more context? if you overload the global operator delete the you should overload operator new too. There you can store required information.

Comment: If you have overloaded the corresponding `operator new(std::size_t)` [i.e. the one that allocates the memory used by the `new` expression] then that function can store data somewhere which associates each pointer it returns with its size.    Then your `operator delete(void *)` can retrieve the size, given the pointer.

Comment: I'd strongly prefer not to store that information myself as memory and performance are a big concern for the application. The size must be stored somewhere already, is it not ? Also, I am aware of the C++14 version of delete with size but sadly it's not being used in my case

Comment: There's no standard way

Comment: Look at the implementation of `free` or `delete` in your compiler's implementation of the standard library. That should tell you everything you need to know about how it stores this information. The obvious caveats apply, about how this is intentionally undocumented, bad design, inherently unportable, and very likely to break if you upgrade your compiler. You seem to already know that. Maybe you should ask a question about your actual problem, rather than how to implement the solution you decided upon? (See also: an X-Y problem)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm trying to log all allocations and deallocations in an application to later on plot the data somewhere else. I guess I'm looking for how valgrind or clang sanitizer do this

Comment: That doesn't sound like a case where *"memory and performance are a big concern for the application"*. You don't run with memory-leak detection or any kind of instrumentation when performance is critical. Once you get the bugs ironed out, you remove all of this code.

Comment: @CodyGray memory and performance are important because the application wouldn't always run with the allocation logging enabled (that's why I'm using preload) and when it does it should have the least impact as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to allocate at particular locations in your `operator new`, based on the size of the underlying allocation. `operator delete` then knows how much to free based on the value of the pointer.

Thus the "store data somewhere" requirement of new is fulfilled by the value of the pointer.

E.g. For allocations of 1 word, allocate between 0x10000000 and 0x1000FFFF, 2 words between 0x10010000 and 0x1001FFFF, etc

You can always `throw bad_alloc` if the range is used up, or allocate a larger amount in that amount's range

Comment: This is probably **a bad idea**. Consider instead *not* overriding `new` and `delete`